# how can set class name to dropdownlist in yii framework?

Tags: yii

I have the dropdownlist already like this:

```
<select id="cateActive" name="cateActive">
  <option selected="selected" value="1">Active</option>
  <option value="0">Deactive</option>
</select>
```

yii framework code:

```
<?php   
    echo CHtml::dropDownList('cateActive', '',              
    array('1' => 'Active', '0' => 'Deactive'),                      
    array('options' => array($model->cate_active=>array('selected'=>true))));
 ?>
```

How can I have the dropdownlist have the class like this:

```
<select id="cateActive" name="cateActive" class="myclass">
      <option selected="selected" value="1">Actyclassive</option>
      <option value="0">Deactive</option>
    </select>
```

thankyou very much your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

General syntax for dropdownlist is

```
dropDownList(string $name, string $select, array $data, array $htmlOptions=array ( ))
```

You can pass class in `htmloptions` parameter.
For your case:

```
<?php   
    echo CHtml::dropDownList('cateActive', '',              
    array('1' => 'Active', '0' => 'Deactive'),                      
    array('options' => array($model->cate_active=>array('selected'=>true))
    "class"=>"myclass",
   )

);
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add the class at last array.

```
echo CHtml::dropDownList('cateActive', '',              
array('1' => 'Active', '0' => 'Deactive'),                      
array('options' => array($model->cate_active=>array('selected'=>true))), 'class' => 'myclass');
```

Comment: your attribute input to the option array and it work, thanks your answer